# I'm trying to print an array with random integers, but for some reason whenever I run the program it only prints out zeros. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, drjava

When I run this program, only zeros are printed out for the random integers

```
public class NumberArray{
  public static void main(String[]args){
    int [] numbers=new int[15];
    double sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length ; i++){
      numbers[i]=(int)Math.random()*100;
      System.out.print(numbers[i]+" ");
      sum+=numbers[i];
    }
    double average=sum/15;

    System.out.println("The average is "+average);
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Put parenthesis around the random and the multiplication with 100. You are only casting the random number to an int, so you get 0

Comment: got it, thank you so much!